# Visual Studio 2017 skips all debug points after bring in c# dll into c++ dll

Tags: debugging, dll, interop, clr, breakpoints

I am trying to abstract out a c++/clr interop. I have a nativeConsole app (will end up being a MFC app), the abstracted InteropToCSharp library and a WinFromControlLib. You can see the intended configuration [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9yeF.png)

The problem I am having is:

- Once I introduce "#Using WinFormControlLib.dll" into InteropToCSharp::Interop it requires the InteropToCSharp and nativeConsole applications are set to clr. However, **after I clear the errors associated with setting the projects to clr visual studio skips all break points**.

Inorder to get WinformControlLib.dll in InteropToCSharp I took the following steps:

#using "WinFormControl.dll was inserted into  InteropToCSharp.h
This required moving to CLR in InteropToCSharp:

- Common Language Runtime support and Debug Information Format was changed from “Zl”  to “Zi”

This also required moving to CLR in nativeConsole:

- Common Language Runtime support and Debug Information Format was changed from “Zl”  to “Zi”
- Enable C++ Exceptions changed from Yes (/EHsc) to Yes with SEH Exceptions (/EHa) because of "‘/clr’ and ‘/EHs’ command-line options are incompatible"
- Because of the error "‘/clr’ and ‘/RTC1’ command-line options are incompatible" the previous state: Basic runtime Checks “Both (/RTC1, equiv. To /RTCsu) (/RTC1) was changed to: “Default”

I have tried with and without “Use Managed Compatibility Mode” Selected.

The file structure can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxrwD.png)

```
// Project: nativeConsole 
// File:    nativeConsole.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "InteropToCSharp.h"

int main()
{
    Interop interop = Interop();
    std::cout << interop.GetVal() << " Hello World!\n" << std::endl;
}
```

```
// Project: InteropToCSharp 
// File:    InteropToCSharp.h
#pragma once

#ifndef WRAPPER_H
#define WRAPPER_H

#using "WinFormControlLib.dll" //Adding this requires clr however after clearing 
                               //errors all debug points are skipped. 

class __declspec(dllexport) Interop
{
public: 
    Interop() {}
    ~Interop() {}
    int GetVal() 
    { 
        return 1234; 
    }
};
#endif
```

```
//Project: WinFormControlLib
//File:    SomeModel.cs
namespace WinFormControlLib.Model
{
    public class SomeModel
    {
        public SomeModel() { }

        public static int GetSomeValue() { return 987; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue and wanted to update in case anyone else is running into the same issues.

The clue is in the output when building the nativeConsole project.
[Output of interest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRyo3.png)

An answer was found in this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/625d9615-9d57-4ecb-a801-cce45746acd9/debugfastlink-with-manged-code?forum=vcgeneral)
but, in short, the solution is set the debugging type to mixed.

- Go to Properties -> Debugging -> Debugging Type and set it to mixed see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnPSV.png).